# Regex: match a pattern, change a part of it

Tags: regex

If you have a text file and want to search and replace a part of a matched pattern, how would you do it with perl one-liners, sed or python?

For example:

```
"653433,78"
```

match with `[0-9]{6},[0-9]{2}`.

Change `,` to `.`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use numbered sub groups. i.e:

Find:

```
([0-9]{6}),([0-9]{2})
```

Replace:

```
\1.\2
```

**Example in Python:**

```python
import re
inp = '653433,78'
out = re.sub(r'([0-9]{6}),([0-9]{2})', r'\1.\2', inp)
print out
```

This would give you:

```
>>>'653433.78'
```

Comment: For using number variables in replacement strings, named reference syntax can be used: `re.sub(pat, r'\g<1>' + f'{my_number}', str)`

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the matched part around the pattern you want to replace and then reuse it in the replace statement.

```
cat yourfile | perl -p -e "s/([0-9]{6}),([0-9]{2})/\\1.\\2/g"
```

A more complex solution with lookahead and lookbacks can also be used (but this will not support wildcards such as * and + for your pattern)

```
cat yourfile | perl -p -e "s/(?<=[0-9]{6}),(?=[0-9]{2})/./g"
```